# how to i add an addition class to store the calculations?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, calculator

I took the code you gave me and edited it so I could add another java class. However now the answer is always 0.0 . I also need to make a `while` loop so that you can make multiple calculations but I don't know what conditions to apply to the loop.

There also needs to be another loop that comes before the part where the user enters a number so that someone can refer back to the past answers  that have been stored in the array. I just need help making the loops and I can make the switch statement for the first loop.

```
package calculator;
import java.util.*;
public class calculator 

{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Operation operationObject = new Operation();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int index = 0;

double calculations[] = new double[100];

System.out.println("Enter first number");
double num1 = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter second number");
double num2 = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter the operation"); 
System.out.println("Addition= + ");
System.out.println("Subtraction= - ");
System.out.println("Divion= / ");
System.out.println("Multiplcation= *");

String operation = input.next();

double result = 0;

switch (operation)  
{
case "+":
    operationObject.addition();
    System.out.println();
    break;
case "-":
    operationObject.subtraction();
    break;
case "/":
    operationObject.division();
    break;
case "*":
    operationObject.multiplication();
    break;
}

storeMem(calculations, result, index);

System.out.println("Your answer is: " + result);
}

static void storeMem(double[] memory, double data, int index)
{
if(index > memory.length)
    index = 0;

memory[index] = data;
index++;
}
}


//other class that contains the operations 


package calculator;

public class Operation{

double num1, num2,  answer;

public void addition(){
    answer = num1 + num2;
    System.out.println(answer);
}

public void subtraction(){
    answer = num1 - num2;
    System.out.println(answer);
}

public void division(){
    answer = num1 / num2;
    System.out.println(answer);
}

public void multiplication(){
    answer = num1 * num2;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to implement another class? Certainly there's resources available for you to help you learn how to do that. It is unclear why / what you need to store in the other class that cannot be in the array

Comment: As far as learning how to create additional classes, try starting here  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: @cricket_007 i need to have another class for this program due to the requirement of the small project. What i mean by i dont know how to implement is that i dont know what part of my program i can have in another class or if i can add something to the code to have another class.

Comment: You can always add to the code to write another class, however it seems like a strange requirement for you to do so if you haven't even learned how to make more than one class with a main method.

Comment: I have learned how to make another class with the main method sorry i didn't make that clear. What i dont know is how can i add to the code to use another class with the main method @cricket_007

Comment: Something like `Class2 other = new Class2();`? You are already using other classes like a `Scanner`. It's no different

Comment: @cricket_007 again sorry for not being specific i need to have like another java class not have another class withing the program if that makes sense.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't make sense, sorry. There's no reason to have another class if you aren't going to use it with anything.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my previous comment. You can make a new file named `Class2.java` and you declare a `public class Class2` in it just like you have `calculator.java` with `public class calculator` in that... That's why I'm confused why you are confused. You already have a class, so you know how to make one, even if you don't think you do

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so your code is a little all over the place and I made it a little more concise in my example of how to do what you're asking. I will start by saying you don't need another class, it's much easier than that, however, you can totally implement the method I made in my example into a class and use it that way if you want (also there are other ways of doing this).

So here is my revised example of your code:

```
//unused import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int index = 0;

    double calculations[] = new double[100];

    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    double num1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number");
    double num2 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the operation"); 
    System.out.println("Addition= + ");
    System.out.println("Subtraction= - ");
    System.out.println("Divion= / ");
    System.out.println("Multiplcation= *");

    String operation = input.next();

    double result = 0;

    switch (operation)  
    {
    case "+":
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;

    case "-":   
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;

    case "/":
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;

    case "*":
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    }

    storeMem(calculations, result, index);

    System.out.println("Your answer is: " + result);
}

static void storeMem(double[] memory, double data, int index)
{
    if(index > memory.length)
        index = 0;

    memory[index] = data;
    index++;
}
}
```

So really you're wanting to store past calculations, so all you need to do is add the result of the current calculation into your array. I simplified this by making a method called **storeMem** for you which does this. The method takes an array to use as the storage, the data to add to it, and an index (an index being the location in the array such as 0, 1, or 400; which I'll explain later). So, you start by calling the **storeMem** method which will then check to see if the index is out of bounds from the array (then reset it to overwrite memory if it is) it will then set the current data equal to the current index in the array, so that it stores your value. Finally the method increments the index. This is helpful so that you can use the **int index** you've created in your program to access the current or previous indexes easily. Because **index** will just be your current stored value, and **index - 1** will be your previous indexed value (previously stored result).

Comment: i changed the original post with the code u gave me and i edited it have another java class. please go back to my orginal post for the update on my issues and code